# How to add javascript variable in html inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have added html code to js variable i need to add js value in html

My code is:

```
var name = sabari;
var html = `
  <div>
    <span>Some HTML here</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>`
    name
  `</span>
  </div>
`;
```

But it shows error how to correct it

Comment: You are trying to concatenate [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) without a concatenation character (+) but that is anyway not how to use them. See dupe

Answer (score 2):

You are using template literal ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)), so wrap your variable in `${}`

```js
var name = 'sabari';
var html = `
  <div>
    <span>Some HTML here</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      ${name}
    </span>
  </div>
`;

console.log(html)
```

Comment: massive dupe....